# Number of feature maps in convolution neural network

Tags: neural-network, convolution

I've read this articles http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/143059/Neural-Network-for-Recognition-of-Handwritten-Di and when I turn to this one:
Layer #0: is the gray scale image of the handwritten character in the MNIST database which is padded to 29x29 pixel. There are 29x29= 841 neurons in the input layer.
Layer #1: is a convolutional layer with six (6) feature maps. There are 13x13x6 = 1014 neurons, (5x5+1)x6 = 156 weights, and 1014x26 = 26364 connections from layer #1 to the previous layer.

How can we get the six(6) feature maps just from convolution on image ?
I think we just get only one feature map. Or am i wrong ?

Comment: really good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786717/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-parameters-for-convolutional-neural-network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing my research around convolution neural network.

**Six different kernels(or filters) are convoluted on the same image to generate six feature map.**

Layer #0: Input image with 29x29 pixels thus have 29*29=841 neuron(input neuron)

Layer #1: Convolutional layer uses 6 different kernels(or filters) of size 5x5 pixel and stride length 2(amount of shift while convoluting input with kernals or filters) which are  convoluted with the input image(29x29) generating 6 different feature maps(13x13) thus 13x13x6=1014 neuron.

Filter size 5x5 and a bias(for weight correction) thus (5x5)+1 neuron and was we have 6 kernals(or filters), gives 6*[(5x5)+1]= 156 neuron.

During convolution we move kernels(or filters) 26 times(13 horizontal move + 13 vertical move) and finally 1014*26=26364 connections from Layer #0 to Layer #1.

You should go through this research paper by Y LeCun, L Bottou, Y Bengio: [Gradient- Based learing applied to document recognition](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98.pdf) Section II to understand convolution neural network(I recommend to read the whole paper).

Another place where you can find detailed explanation and python implementation fo CNN is [here](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap6.html). If you have time I recommend to go through this site for more details about deep learning.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you get six feature maps by convolving with six different kernel on the same image.