# Why does my keras model have so many parameters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

```
model = ke.Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),activation='relu',input_shape=(360,720,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 2, 2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (3,3)))
model.add(Dropout(.3))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

the above is currently the architecture for my CNN. However, it says it  has 1.8m trainable parameters. Why is this so? I thought the first layer gives (32*4 = 128 params), but then how do I find how many params are in the rest of the model?

My understanding was that the CNN architecture should only depend on the filtering and max-pooling since they are shared weights. Why then do I have so many parameters? How should I go about reducing the number?

I am **not** asking how to find the number of params using "summary". I am asking why my model has so many parameters and how I can reduce that number. I do not understand intuitively why this model should have 1.8million trainable parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the number of parameters for convolutional neural network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786717/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-parameters-for-convolutional-neural-network)

Answer (score 3):

Use the summary to confirm the following (trust me, there will be an answer :D ):

- After the second conv you've got a shape like `(None, 358,718,32)`
- The Pooling then gives you something very near `(None, 120, 240, 32)`
- And the `Flatten` layer gave you `(None, 120*240*32)` which is `(None, 921600)`!!!!

This is the reason of so many parameters!

The dense layer will have 2 weights for each input, plus 2 biases, totaling 1843202 parameters just for the Dense layer.

You need more Convs + Poolings to gradually reduce the size before throwing that huge amount into a Dense layer.

Answer (score 0):

A good method to drastically lower these parameters is to add:
`subsample=(2, 2)` (careful it lowers the resolution of images/data) in all the Convolutional layers above that Flatten layer,
if subsample doesn't work then it is `stride=(2, 2)`.